# jQuery Sortable - Drag items into previously dragged items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I create a drag & drop interface with input field masks based on a users choice. Therefore you can drag blocks, rearrange them and drag several fields inside of a block.

I now can create new blocks, but I'm unable to drag fields inside these blocks.

```
<div class="draggable">

    <h2>Structure</h2>
    <div class="structure">
        <div class="item1">New block</div>
        <div class="item1">New headline</div>
    </div>

    <h2>Fields</h2>
    <div class="fields1 fields2">
        <div class="item2">Date</div>
        <div class="item2">Time</div>
        <div class="item2">Relation</div>
        <div class="item2">Text</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="sortable"></div>
```

My   jQuery code looks like this, however I am not able drag fields to strcture elemnts I previously dragged to .sortable.

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true
});

$( ".item1" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});

$( ".item2" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable .item1",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});

$( ".sortable .item1" ).sortable({
    revert: true
});
```

This is my current state of this project https://jsfiddle.net/alphafrau/egcbL5nt/5/

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want like this?

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
  });

  $(".item1").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(".sortable .item1").sortable({
        revert: true
      });
    }
  });

  $(".item2").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable .item1",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
```

```css
h1 {
  padding: 0 0 0 350px;
}

.draggable {
  background: #c9c9c9;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

.draggable .item1 {
  background: lime;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.draggable .item2 {
  background: Yellow;
  border: 2px solid Orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.sortable {
  background: Orange;
  border: 2px solid OrangeRed;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 0 350px;
}

.sortable .item1 {
  background: fuchsia;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="draggable">

  <h2>Structure</h2>
  <div class="structure">
    <div class="item1">New block</div>
    <div class="item1">New headline</div>
  </div>

  <h2>Fields</h2>
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="item2">Date</div>
    <div class="item2">Time</div>
    <div class="item2">Relation</div>
    <div class="item2">Text</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="sortable">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this works only if I clone the items from "Fields". These items should only be usable once, so they mustn't be cloned.

If I use this instead nothing happends:

`$(".fields").sortable({ connectWith: ".sortable .item1" });`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the html hasn’t the ".sortable .item1“ elements on initial page, so you might binding an event when the ".sortable .item1“ elements is ready, thanks